# Creating column chart in Excel with Secondary Axis

Tags: excel, charts, bar-chart, quickchart

The following are 3 tables I have in my excel file.

| Gender | Participants (n = 200) | % |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Female | 160 | 80 |
| Male | 40 | 20 |

| Area | Participants (n = 200) | % |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Rural | 80 | 40 |
| Urban | 120 | 60 |

| Average Salary | Participants (n = 200) | % |
| --- | --- | --- |
| <5000 | 40 | 20 |
| >5000 | 160 | 80 |

I'm trying to combine to create 3 axis charts for each table and another chart that combines all the data from the 3 tables.

The combined chart is supposed to look something like the following. But I'm unable to add secondary axis no matter what I try. I don't know how I can create percentage as a secondary column.

[image: 3-axis chart]

Can this be achieved in Excel? I even tried creating it in quickchart.io but I don't know how to do it. Please help.